# bitmap conversion to webp gives signal 11

Tags: android, bitmap, webp

My Android app gives me this error when I am converting a bitmap to WEBP format:

```
  #00  pc 00000000004125c4  /system/lib/libskia.so
  #01  pc 000000000042e350  /system/lib/libskia.so
  #02  pc 000000000042db78  /system/lib/libskia.so
  #03  pc 000000000042dc60  /system/lib/libskia.so (WebPPictureImportRGBA+36)
  #04  pc 00000000003a1fd0  /system/lib/libskia.so (_ZN18SkWEBPImageEncoder8onEncodeEP9SkWStreamRK8SkBitmapi+444)
  #05  pc 00000000000a216f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #06  pc 0000000001aabea3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCompress+158)
  #07  pc 0000000001aad39b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Bitmap.compress+230)
  #08  pc 00000000000a9e41  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #09  pc 00000000004087e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+232)
  #10  pc 00000000000b1115  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+136)
  #11  pc 00000000001ef3fd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter34ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_9ArtMethodEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+200)
  #12  pc 00000000001e99ad  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+492)
  #13  pc 0000000000402bb3  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+322)
  #14  pc 00000000000a0a14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #15  pc 00000000001cc463  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+290)
  #16  pc 00000000001d0fcb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+114)
  #17  pc 00000000001e9993  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+466)
  #18  pc 0000000000402bb3  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+322)
  #19  pc 00000000000a0a14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #20  pc 00000000001cc463  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+290)
  #21  pc 00000000001d0fcb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+114)
  #22  pc 00000000001e9993  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+466)
  #23  pc 0000000000402bb3  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+322)
  #24  pc 00000000000a0a14  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #25  pc 00000000001cc463  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+290)
  #26  pc 00000000001d0f35  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter30EnterInterpreterFromEntryPointEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameE+92)
  #27  pc 00000000003f7bb3  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+706)
  #28  pc 00000000000ae893  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+34)
  #29  pc 000000000208fc09  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.View.performClick+276)
  #30  pc 0000000002109f95  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.view.View$PerformClick.run+40)
  #31  pc 000000000182fbe5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.handleCallback+48)
  #32  pc 000000000182fc43  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage+54)
  #33  pc 0000000001e24e39  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.os.Looper.loop+1948)
  #34  pc 00000000018445f3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.app.ActivityThread.main+814)
  #35  pc 00000000000a9e41  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #36  pc 00000000004088e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+228)
  #37  pc 00000000000b113f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+178)
  #38  pc 0000000000318d21  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+56)
  #39  pc 000000000031a0b3  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12InvokeMethodERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectS4_S4_j+766)
  #40  pc 00000000002c12d5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Method_invokeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_S3_+40)
  #41  pc 00000000005ae931  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-oj.oat (java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke+116)
  #42  pc 000000000236cf89  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+100)
  #43  pc 000000000236e3df  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+1978)
  #44  pc 00000000000a9e41  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+64)
  #45  pc 00000000004088e9  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+228)
  #46  pc 00000000000b113f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+178)
  #47  pc 0000000000318d21  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+56)
  #48  pc 0000000000318b33  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+266)
  #49  pc 000000000027b61f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDSt9__va_list+426)
  #50  pc 000000000006837d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
  #51  pc 0000000000069c63  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcRKNS_6VectorINS_7String8EEEb+498)
  #52  pc 000000000000199f  /system/bin/app_process32
  #53  pc 0000000000016d8d  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+48)
  #54  pc 00000000000015bc  /system/bin/app_process32
```

I don't know exactly where that error occurs but my guess is when I try to compress a bitmap to the WEBP format in here:

```
public String saveImage(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if(bitmap != null) {
        File folder = new File(getFilesDir() + "/packs", id);
        if (!folder.exists())
            folder.mkdirs();
        String stickerName = "sticker" + String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimeMillis())) + ".webp";
        File filename = new File(folder, stickerName);
        try {
            if (!filename.exists())
                filename.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 100, out);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stickerName;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The bitmap is created inside a custom view of mine and than saved as WEBP, but it gives me an error every time I try. As I said I don't know how to debug this error message so if I am totally wrong please say.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey!
I've got the same error on some of the devices. Will keep posted if I find something useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up using [libwebp](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp) instead of `Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 100, out);` and it now works fine. Here is a tutorial on how to use libwebp http://masashi-k.blogspot.com/2014/02/webp-in-android.html.

Comment: You didn't have any errors following that tutorial ? Did you use Eclipse or Android Studio? I can't get it to work :(

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: It ended up giving me the same error. I will just try the solution you posted.

Add [Android Compressor Library](https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor) to your `build.gradle` and copy and paste this function (if you have a `Bitmap`)

```
public static void saveBitmap(String folder, String imageName, Bitmap bitmap, Context context) throws IOException {
        File temp = new File(folder, "temp_" + imageName);

        try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(temp)) {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        }

        new Compressor(context)
                .setQuality(90)
                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP)
                .setDestinationDirectoryPath(folder) // Saving in the same folder temp file is at
                .compressToFile(temp, imageName); // Takes the temp file and creates a new one with the name passed as second argument

        temp.delete(); // Deleting temp file

    }
```

If you are wondering why i'm saving a temporary `PNG` file before saving the desired `WEBP`, it's because that library doesn't take a `Bitmap` as argument, it only works with `File`.

The library logs an error saying "the file should be a `JPEG`" but it is working fine so far anyway, the PNG alpha channel is being kept in the WEBP so i'm ignoring that error.